# Wordpress: Run Task in the Background

Tags: php, wordpress, asynchronous, woocommerce

In my WooCommerceShop, a User uploads an image. This image needs to be processed (resize, trim, ..) on the server side. At the moment, its done with an AJAX Request so the User has to wait for the result and it needs over 20 seconds, much to much time!

How can processes be run in the background? So I basically want to trigger the imageprocessing action and it should run in the background, the user needs to be able to change the current site he's on.

I read a lot about WP_CRON but this doesn't seem to be the right was because i don't want to schedule the action. Another thing I found is the Async Task Library by TechCrunch (http://techcrunch.com/2014/07/31/wp-async-task-our-new-open-source-library/) but I can't get it running.

How is this kind of problem normally solved? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, many frameworks can simply use a queuing class (e.g. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues), Zend, etc.) along with something like Beanstalkd or Amazon SQS... but as far as I can tell, WordPress nor WooCommerce has such a class. That said, [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/amazon-sqs/woocommerce/) has something to connect WooCommerce with Amazon SQS but it might not be what you're looking for. There will probably be some custom coding in your future and you'll need to alter or extend the WooCommerce code. WP_CRON could work, but you would first need to find the script that's doing the image processing. Then, you could alter the script that does the upload->image_processing into one that just does an upload into a specific directory. You would need to have some way to recognize which user/item/whatever this image belongs to (like a file naming convention). Then, you could have WP_CRON (or just a regular cron job if you have access) run a script that processes the images in that directory, maybe even using the original WooCommerce code that you cut out of the uploading process. I hope this helps you get onto the right track at least, but what you're needing probably can't be solved with a simple "boxed" solution.